# "flutter doctor" not working

Tags: installation, flutter

I've downloaded Flutter SDK as mentioned on https://flutter.io/setup-windows/ and also extracted it. Now when I try to run any Flutter command on the `flutter_console.bat` or any other CLI the prompts starts blinking forever and nothing happens! I've set the path correctly. Did not find any help from web!

Answer (score 19):

Try running the `flutter_console.bat` as **Administrator**

Comment: how to run this on the windows machine?

Answer (score 13):

If you delete cache folder under bin to solve some installation issues, this cause a endless loop in flutter doctor. This was my case.

Comment: This was the solution for me. Go and delete: `C:/flutter/bin/cache`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when my flutter directory wasn't located directly in my C:/ drive ("C:/flutter")

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same issue on windows. Try extracting the flutter folder in this path C:\Users\YourAccountName\AppData\Local.
Then edit your environment variable and add C:\Users\YourAccountName\AppData\Local\flutter\bin. This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have installed plug-in of **flutter and dart**
for the working of flutter doctor you need to create system environment variables of - **flutter**, **git** , **cmd** and **powershell**

[image]

like show in image just copy paste path of
**your path may different **

example:

```
C:\flutter\bin
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, reason was our proxy. I unplugged the network cable and used mobile network of my smartphone via usb host function, that worked for me. After checking and configuring with flutter doctor every following attempt to start flutter doctor or flutter help was successful even with "normal" network.

Answer (score 0):

I extracted flutter to C:\Program Files\ and had same problem. Running command prompt as Administrator did the trick for me. Or extract flutter to another dir where you don't need admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

First, if in your system there is no git installed then first install git.

For my case, I just deleted the whole flutter folder. Download again, extract the folder, cut and paste to the c drive and then update both user variable path and system variable path. I added "C:\flutter\bin" this path inside user variable path and system variable path. Also make sure that:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe
```

these paths are exist inside the system variable path. Finally I run "flutter doctor" and successfully it run. I also check "dart --version" and there is no problem.

(if you have any confusion about user variable path and system variable path then simply press widow button the type "env" then you will see "Edit the system Environment variables" then press enter and at the last you will see "Environment variables" clik on it and you will see 2 option for variable. One for user variable and another for system variable. select "path" for both and edit.)

Answer (score 0):

My answer is somehow different, although I was using Visual Studio Code, I didn't find the flutter doctor option after pressing ctrl+shift+p.
I solved this issue after finding out, that I didn't choose the trusted system of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

- open your path /flutter/bin
- then delete cache folder
- open terminal
- flutter doctor -v

This will fix all problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can just do this>
navigate to flutter bin
*cd  C:\flutter\bin*
*C:\flutter\bin> flutter doctor*

Answer (score 0):

I installed fresh right now and if you run flutter doctor with console under administrator rights it works for me. If not I have the same behavior as described in your post.

Answer (score 0):

I had initially installed the flutter SDK files at C:/Program Files, and instead had to move them to C:/. So once the Path was C:/flutter/bin for the environment variable, it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem on macOS, when I use the

```
flutter doctor
```

command, there is no response, then I try the

```
flutter doctor -v
```

command, and I get an insufficient permission prompt in the

```
~/.pub-cache
```

folder.

After I authorize the read and write permissions, the problem is solved.

You can try this method.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I first unpacked flutter to the root of the C drive, and then moved it to another folder. When unpacking to the root of the C drive, the folder was created under administrator rights, and after moving the cmd without administrator rights, it did not have access. In my case, I just repacked flutter again, right into the folder

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same issue, just delete the cache folder and then tried it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Delete cache folder in `flutter/bin/cache` and start

```
flutter doctor
```

flutter will download necessary data back.

Answer (score -1):

For some reason the latest version that I installed did not work! Installing lower version with same configuration worked!

Comment: Don't think using an older version is really a good solution.